# Unable to install Sql server 2008 r2 in custom action

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, installshield-2012

If I directly run the Sql 2008 r2 is installed successfully. But if I add SQLServer2008R2.exe as a custom action After Setup Complete , Sql Server installation failed even if the installation process took longer time (Stop to install) than normal with no error message. I run the InstallShield 2012 Express created Setup.exe as administrator.

The Sql server 2008 r2 file are transferred by InstallShield setup.exe to a application installed folder.

I tried many different scenarios, still unsuccessful. Please help me.

Comment: If you run the sqlserver2008r2.exe with the "/?" command-line argument in a command prompt, the installer will extract and then display all the optional command-line arguments. Maybe this will give you a way to turn on verbose installer logging in your custom action to see what's causing it to fail to install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you conclude that the SQL Server installation failed, when there was no error message?

Take a look at the installation logs of SQL Server 2008 R2 to get a better understanding of what actually is happening.

In case, you do not see the log file for SQL Server installation, please follow the steps in the below URL to enable verbose windows installer logging:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2005/03/29/help-me-help-you-if-you-have-setup-bugs.aspx

To know the command line arguments to install SQL Server in silent mode, take a look at:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259.aspx

Although the above URL lists command line parameters for SQL Server 2016, it should give you a fair idea of what aspects of the installation are configurable.(You can verify the command line parameters for 2008 R2 by following the steps in the previous comment)

I suspect that we might not be passing the correct parameter to the SQL Server setup. The log file of the SQL Server installation should have the command line parameters being used . To know the command line parameters, you can as well make use of Process Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

sql server uses msi while your setup uses diffrent msi. in that case sql should close other msi to complete the job.hence setup should be ended while this will terminate sql setup. and this coause a deadlock and sql stops until terminates without success